# How can i make adaptive block and add there blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have this html code:

```
<div class = "form_wrappers">
 <div class = "form">Hello
 </div>
</div>
<a class = "destiny_add">
```

And jQuery code:

```
 function addBlock() {
    $('.destiny_add').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form_wrappers').append($('form'))
    });
}
```

I want to add a lot of `<div class = "form">` in `<div class = "form_wrappers>`

How can i make it?
Now it tottaly does not work

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: I wanted to make .form_wrappers  rubber block and then add there a lot .form blocks

Comment: Like basket is internet-shops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

- Your jquery is inside the function 'addBlock' which is never called.
- You're missing the dot in your append `$('form')`
- You need to append the html of the element, not the element itself.
- I also included your code in the `.ready()` to make sure the elements are loaded before jquery tries to run it.

See the code below

```
$(function() {
      $('.destiny_add').on('click', function (e) {
          $('.form_wrappers').append('<div class="form">'+$('.form').html()+'</div>');
      });
})
```